# ElectronJS. Set Window name or identify which window emitting the event

Tags: javascript, web, electron

Is there a way to identify which window emitting the event using ipcRenderer, in order to subscribe this window listen to external events?
The event handler looks like this:

```
_registerListener(event, {windowName, id, eventName}) {

    this._ems[id].on(eventName, (value)=>{
        this._windows[windowName].webContents.send(eventName, value);
    });
}
```

The partial solution I've found is to set name property of a window in WebRenderer context.
The only way I've found is to use executeJavaScript method when creating a BrowserWindow:

```
mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("window.name='mainWindow';");
```

But this solution is not working for me, because the script passed to this method is executing after scripts linked in HTML header.

Is there another way to select BrowserWindow name or identify one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is found. We could identify the window by its webContent.
The Electron ipcEvent has the field **sender** which represents window's webContent.
So in my case, the solution is to make closure like this:

```
 _registerListener(event, {id, eventName}) {

    this._ems[id].on(eventName, (value)=>{
        event.sender.webContents.send(eventName, value);
    });
 }
```